# Двойное отрицание

Tags: javascript

Как понимать двойное отрицание: `!!` (например, в JavaScript)?

Comment: и в каких языках используется?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/

Answer (score 114, accepted):

В javascript всякое значение может быть интерпретировано как Boolean. (Правила этой интерпретации довольно сложны и не вполне интуитивны.)

Если вы укажете какое-нибудь выражение там, где ожидается Boolean (например, внутри `if`'а), оно проинтерпретируется как Boolean, и всё. Но если вы хотите *получить* соответствующий Boolean (например, чтобы вернуть его из функции или присвоить другой переменной), вам нужен трюк, который заставит систему проинтерпретировать ваше выражение в булевом контексте.

Для этой цели традиционно используется двойное отрицание: первое отрицание "требует" булев контекст, так что выражение интерпретируется как Boolean, а второе отрицание "отменяет" первое.

Из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Оператор отрицания: возвращает `false` если его аргумент может быть преобразован в `true`, в противном случае возвращает `true`.

---

Для справки: значения, которые в булевом контексте будут проинтерпретированы как `false` суть следующие:

- число `0.0`
- число `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- пустая строка
- ну и конечно `false`

Все остальные значения будут проинтерпретированы как `true`.

Пример: если `x` -- объект или `null`, вместо

```
if (x != null)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

можно воспользоваться изящным

```
return !!x;
```

---

По поводу других языков: подобный трюк нужен в основном в слабо типизированных языках вроде javascript'а, в котором значением переменной может быть и true/false, и undefined, и функция, и объект. Применение двойного отрицания гарантирует отсутствие неожиданностей в поведении полученного объекта: его тип то уж точно boolean. Однако, я встречал этот трюк и в C++ в контексте явного преобразования указателя в `bool`.

Comment: хороший пример эталонного ответа

Comment: Это дает какой-либо выигрыш по сравнению с return Boolean(x) или они абсолютно равноценны?

Comment: @mirus: насколько я понимаю, `Boolean(x)` то же что и `!!x`. Stackoverflow [подсказывает](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1407769/276994), что также `+x` -- то же, что и `Number(x)`. (Автор ответа считает такие паттерны хаком.) Заметьте, что `new Boolean(x)` -- не то же самое:

    typeof(!!x) === "boolean"
    typeof(Boolean(x)) === "boolean"
    typeof(new Boolean(x)) === "object"

Comment: да с new  Boolean ваще есть прикол, это объект и получаем что new Boolean(false) если проверить в условие вернет true
т.е 
var v = new Boolean(false);
if(v) alert('во как');

Comment: @ilyas: Так и есть: тип `new Boolean(false)` -- объект, он будет интерпретироваться как false только если `null`. А вот тип `Boolean(false)` -- boolean.