# Как эффективно обернуть не-последовательность в iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.x, итераторы

Есть тестовая обёртка, она внутри себя использует `.assertEquals`, который сравнивает два значения. Есть N тестов, которые используют эту обёртку.

```
def example(actual, expected):
    message = 'not equal!!!111'
    self.assertEquals(actual, expected, message)

example(1, 2)
```

Я хочу расширить функционал, чтобы стало можно проверять `assertIn`, но для существующих тестов поведение не поменялось. То есть:

1. Кортежи, списки и словари передавать как есть
2. Строки и числа оборачивать в iterable (вероятно, кортеж) из одного элемента. Да, строка - iterable, но я хочу сохранить для строк старое поведение.
3. Если я захочу передать iterable как единственный элемент, я сам оберну его в кортеж

```
example(1, 2) # fail
example(1, [1, 2]) #pass
example(1, ([1, 2],)) # fail
example([1, 2], ([1, 2],)) # pass
example('a', 'abc') # fail
example('a', ('a', 'b', 'c')) # pass
example('a', list('abc')) # pass
```

Пока что я придумал вариант через `hasattr`:

```
def example(actual, expected):
    message = 'not equal!!!111'
    if not hasattr(expected, '__iter__'):
        expected = expected,
    self.assertIn(actual, expected, message)
```

Либо так:

```
def example(actual, expected):
    message = 'not equal!!!111'
    if hasattr(expected, '__iter__'):
        self.assertIn(actual, expected, message)
    else:
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected, message)
```

Есть ли слабые места у этого решения? Как сделать лучше/короче? Какое-нибудь волшебное приведение типов вроде [!! в JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/188946/181472)?

Comment: либо проверять на isinstance(theElement, collections.Iterable), больше тут ничего не придумать

Comment: @FeroxTL похоже на то. Я надеялся, что есть какой-нибудь ещё более простой способ. Придётся самому себе писать ответ )