# объясните работу кода JS - сдвоенный оператор !?

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста работу сдвоенного оператора JS !!
Вот тут:
https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/44911/

автор пишет :
"!!" — является проверкой как определена ли переменная и является истиной, а "!!!" — как определена переменная и является ложью.

```js
if(!!undefinedVar)
  alert("Not undefined");
else
  alert("Undefined");
```

Если запустить предлагаемый пример кода - то мы ничего не увидим ибо в консоли сразу вылетает Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: undefinedVar is not defined

Я подумал что пример устарел (2012 год)
Но вот тут (2018 год):
https://habr.com/ru/post/421817/

автор по прежнему использует тот же фрагмент кода:

```
className={cx('label', !!labelClass && labelClass)}
```

Объясните пожалуйста зачем используется сдвоенный оператор !!

Comment: [ответ про !!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/188953/215651)

Comment: чтобы привести любое значение к `true` или `false`

Answer (score 1):

допустим ситуацию, что переменная может быть не задана, т.е. `undefined`, так вот чтобы не было ошибок в коде, например, если у Вас проверка `if(!!var) {...}`, то первый `!` превращает `undefined` в `true`, а второй `!` впревращает в `false`, т.е. получается, что переменной нет и код работает, надеюсь понятно объяснил)

```js
let x;
console.log(x);

if (!!x) {
  console.log('не сработает');
} else {
  console.log(!!x);
  console.log('сработает');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
В предыдущем примере кода я не определил переменную и поэтому вышел Error. Теперь все ясно!