# Какая разница между оператором !! (not not) и простым if блоком без ничего?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
const a = 4;

if(!!a){
  console.log("not not"); 
}
if(a){
  console.log("truish");
}
```

Выведет с начало `not not` потом `truish`.

Какая разница между двумя этими подходами ?

Этот вопрос не про то как работает оператор `!! (или not not)` а какая разница между двумя этими подходами наверху.

Comment: В данном конкретном примере - ни в чём.

Comment: Мне кажется, что такие вопросы на SO уже были.

Comment: вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188946/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: @0xdb какой еще дубликат я разницу спрашиваю а не то как работает этот оператор

Comment: @nick_n_a ссылка в студию где говорится про разницы данного оператора с простым `if`-ом

Comment: Так это и есть суть того, как он (оператор) работает.

Comment: @nick_n_a что есть ?я не понял

Comment: Я же не спрашиваю как работает функция FileExists(filename), я спрашиваю разницу между Print(filename) и FileExists(filename). Вот так я вижу ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!!` - преобразует выражение (переменную) в логический тип явно,
то есть в вашем примере

```
console.log(a) //4
console.log(!!a) //true
```

с точки зрения вашего примера особо разницы нет.
Но если написать:

```
if(a === true) //так не сработает
if(!!a === true) //так сработает
```

фактически `!!a === Boolean(a)`

---

интересная особенность

```
'0' == 0 // true
!!'0' == !!0 // false
```